# Command button array

Tags: .net, vb.net, button, control-array

How can I create a array of buttons in VB.NET?

```
 cmdButton(0)
 cmdButton(1)
 cmdButoon(2)
```

Comment: VB.NET is not VB6 0 control arrays do not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array like this

```
Dim btnCommand(2) As Button
```

But you will have to add it to your form and add a click handler in order for this to do a anything useful:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim y As Integer = 25
    Dim btnCommand(2) As Button
    For i As Integer = 0 To btnCommand.Length - 1
        btnCommand(i) = New Button
        Me.Controls.Add(btnCommand(i))
        With btnCommand(i)
            .Top = y
            .Tag = i
            .Text = "Button " + i.ToString
        End With
        y += 25
        AddHandler btnCommand(i).Click, AddressOf ButtonArray_Click
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonArray_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim btn As Button = sender
    MsgBox("Button " + btn.Tag.ToString + " was clicked")
End Sub
```

Comment: thanx men.. but this is my code in vb and i wanted to convert it to vb.net...i.e. i want three buttons to access the same code when i click them

Comment: thanx men.. but this is my code in vb and i wanted to convert it to vb.net...i.e. i want three buttons to access the same code when i click them:

Comment: thanx men.. but this is my code in vb and i wanted to convert it to vb.net...i.e. i want three buttons to access the same code on them same form when i click them: 

Private Sub cmdButton_Click(Index As Integer)
 ......   
 oQuestions(CLng(lblQuestion.Tag)).UserAnswer = iAnswer
   
 Ret = GetQuestion(Index) ' Index is 0 or 1 - (cmdButton_Click(0) or cmdButton_Click(1))
....
    cmdButton(1).Enabled = True
   End If
    cmdButton(0).Enabled = True
    cmdButton(2).Visible = False
  Else
.....

Comment: Well - that is what you should have posted in your original question then. Start a new question with this code explaining what you want to ultimately achieve.